# TomEE deploy failed datasource not found

Tags: java, datasource, web-deployment, apache-tomee, openejb

I want to deploy a war file to TomEE but fails with:

Caused by:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
      Name openejb/Resource/application_name/mysql_ds" not found.
```

If I restart the server, the deploy goes fine but only once, then the same error encounters.

I have defined datasource in WEB-INF/resources.xml file

```
<tomee>
    <Resource id="mysql_ds" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver  = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl     = jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;autoReconnect=true
        UserName    = user
        Password    = password
        JtaManaged  = true
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

Also i should mention that there is another cloned application(dev mode) with same configuration and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can either you use `WEB-INF/resources.xml` to define one or more datasources or the `tomee.xml` file inside the `<tomee-home>/conf` folder, as noted in the [corresponding section](https://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html) of the TomEE project documentation:

> A DataSource can be declared via xml in the /conf/tomee.xml file or in a WEB-INF/resources.xml file

However, the syntax for `resources.xml`is slightly *different* from the container-wide definition. For a `resources.xml` bundled with your web-application it should be formulated as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="mysql_ds" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver  = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl     = jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;autoReconnect=true
        UserName    = user
        Password    = password
        JtaManaged  = true
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

Note well, that the tag `<resources>` is different from `<tomee>` given in your question. This should work for a default TomEE environment. See also: comment by rmannibucau.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Note that if conflicting definitions are found the resource will be resolved contextually (using the classloader) so you can still deploy 2 conflicting resources in 2 different webapps.

Comment: @rmannibucau That's a good hint / clarification for such a case, thx.